# Using Amazon SWF and Reactive Web Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I have general question regarding Amazon SWF and web application which has a reactive style. For example, I have a shopping website where user ad products to cart, validate the quantity, enter the shipping and billing address, payment processing, order shipping and tracking. If I implement a work flow for the order fulfillment, how this should be designed in the SWF. Do this order fulfillment work flow begin only after all inputs received? How this work flow notifies to the customer on the progress of order process, any validation issues etc. How this should be distributed?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use SWF to perform backend order fulfillment and a separate data store to hold the order information and status. When an order is configured through the website the data store is updated. Later when the order is placed a workflow instance is created for it. The workflow uses information (by loading it using activities) from the data store. Then the workflow updates the data store using activities and the website queries the status and other progress information of the workflow from the data store.

Another option is to use execution state feature of SWF. See [Exposing Execution State](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/workflowimpl.html) from SWF Developer Guide.

The [Cadence](https://github.com/uber/cadence) (which is open sourced version of SWF) in the near future is going to add a query feature. It would allow synchronously query for the workflow state through the service API. It is different from execution state as it would allow multiple query types and query parameters.